# Java ArrayList<String> form comma-separated strings in square brackets

Tags: java, json, spring, arraylist, httpresponse

I am calling an end-point and I get the request body looking like this.

```
{"page":6,"name":"Fly","myList":["123","657","983","112"]}
```

So I am Creating an **org.json.JSONObject** like `JSONObject repsonseObj = new JSONObject(repsonse.getBody());`

I can now do

```
(int)repsonseObj.get("page");
(String)repsonseObj.get("name");
```

I am trying to covert **"myList"** into a Java **ArrayList of String**.
I can pull it out using a **JSONArray** object and use a for-loop to populate an instance of ArrayList.
Also tried something like this below using an ObjectMapper for jackson.databind

```
    myListVar = mapper.readValue((String)repsonse.getString("myList"), new TypeReference<ArrayList<String>>(){}); 
//That gives an error saying "myList" is not a string. Surely I am missing something here.
```

**I want to keep the sequence of the numbers**.
Is there a more elegant solution for this? I tried looking at the **StringUtils**, **ArrayUtils** from java.lang. I just can't seem to put my finger on a better solution. Can someone point me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: I think this `Is there a more elegant solution for this? ` question is opinion-based .

Answer (score 3):

Actually why don't you parse the whole object instead of just the list?

```
public class MyClass {
    private Integer page;
    private String name;
    private List<String> myList;

    //getters, setters
}
```

And this parses the JSON to a variable

```
MyClass myClass = objectMapper.readValue("{\"page\":6,\"name\":\"Fly\",\"myList\":[\"123\",\"657\",\"983\",\"112\"]}", MyClass.class);
```

EDIT:

As it turned out in the comments you need your properties in the JSON to have different names than in your class. This can be easily achieved by annotating the class properties with `@JsonProperty` as @Dragos Ionut suggested. Just do the following

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {
    @JsonProperty("page")
    private Integer otherNameThanPage;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String otherNameThanName;
    @JsonProperty("myList")
    private List<String> otherNameThanMyList;


    //getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Definitely the better option: Jackson will detect the list type by reflection here. I never understood why developers try to avoid creating classes :-).

Comment: Actually I always design my REST APIs to contain the root element as an object (not an array). It's easier to add data to it (like pagination for example) and you don't have to deploy the clients at the same time because the API is still working

Comment: I am actually Using a class to send the data to the client for pagination. However the request POJO on the microservice side has different names and fields than the POJO in the calling application. The mapping will not match. So I am trying to manually map the request-values to the POJO before sending to the JSP.

Comment: Why don't you annoted the fields in this case to match your json.Something like this: @JsonProperty("strVal")

Comment: @DragosIonut I think that is the correct solution as well, I edited my answer accordingly :)